# Inserting SQL Data into Linked (Foreign Key) Tables in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables linked by a foreign key.  Example:

> "CREATE TABLE one (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data REAL, time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now')));"
>
> "CREATE TABLE two (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, parent INTEGER, CONSTRAINT fc_two FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES one(id));"

So I'd like to do an INSERT INTO with an embedded JOIN, but I already tried (and then Googled it) and apparently it doesn't work.  I did find a way to do it using something called @@Identity but that doesn't seem to work with SQLite.  Basically, I need to:

1. Insert data into one
2. **Find the value of "id" for the row I just inserted into one**
3. Insert data into two using the id value I just got from one

1 and 3 are easy, but to get 2 I would need to query for the one I just inserted.  None of the data columns (except id) are unique, and the one unique combination (the set of all non-id columns as a whole is unique, just not any individual one) is impossible to reliably query against.

What's the best way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: Nice, that does work.  However, I now have another problem.  Using last_insert_rowid() in an INSERT statement works fine, but then the next INSERT statement fails.  I need to somehow "store" that temporary value and use it in multiple INSERT statements into the second table.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: So what stops you from saving value of last_insert_rowid() to a variable and providing it within other parameters (as selectionArgs) for further insert statements?

Comment: The issue is that if I execute a SQLite statement and grab the value, then execute another SQLite statement using the value, it uses two statements.  I'm not sure if this is an issue for locking, since technically a single transaction should be a single SQLite statement because in between the two inserts, the database is in an inconsistent state.  If I break up the statement (SQL statement -> C variable -> SQL Statement) it breaks up the transaction.  I'd like a way to keep it all within a single string of SQL... or is that not a problem to split it up like that?

Comment: It will not be a problem if you will use db.beginTransaction(), then do all your insert operations and call db.setTransactionSuccessful(), db.endTransaction().

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a beginTransaction() function; transactions are handled in the SQL code; however, all statements from the BEGIN TRANSACTION and END TRANSACTION statements must be contained in a single block of SQL.  That's my problem; I can't store intermediate values within that SQL block in SQLite.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have beginTransaction(). But SQLiteDatabase class does have all methods listed in my comment above.

Comment: There is no such thing as SQLiteDatabase in SQLite.  SQLite is C; it's not object-oriented.  There also is no sqlite3_*() function that seems to work in that manner.  If there is I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know why, but I thought you are using android. Have you tried to declare sqlite variable and select identity in it? Then you can use variable value for your insert operations.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support variables... at least I can't figure out how they would work.  It looks like using a temporary table is the only way to do it.

Comment: In any case, it looks like the temporary table will work.  It would be nice to have variables in SQLite, but oh well.  Thanks for your help!